# range of a linear operator on a finite dimensional vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Consider a linear operator $L: X \to X$ where X is finite dimension vector space. Is it true that the range of L, $Range (L)$, is given by the subspace generated by the linear combinations of $v_i$,  where $v_i $ is the eigenvector corresponding to some $\lambda_i$ eigenvalue?

Does this hold also in infinite dimension (if it holds)?

The motivation for this is connected with the Hill Yosida theorem which states that for a strongly continuous with exponential bound $|T(t)|\leq Me^{\omega t}$ then the spectrum of the generator $A$ lies on the left of $\omega$ plus some other growth conditions on the resolvent. So I was asking if in some sense the eigenvectors define the range of the operator meaning that the range is a subsbace of the linear combinations of the eigenvectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An invertible operator that is non-diagonalizable should provide a counterexample.

Comment: For instance rotation by $90^\circ$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ has no eigenvectors, but its range is all of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @JamieRadcliffe Yes, it should be noted though that this example does not work anymore over the complex numbers though.

Comment: Also, who voted to delete this answer? It answers the question of the OP!